# How to create a handle Class manager Api with Alamofire in swift 2.1?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to create a Class APIManager to manager apis use thirdparty Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire , swift 2.1 . Anybody help me !!!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/Moya/Moya

Comment: Thanks @tskulbru .. (y)

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

[Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) can solve this for you in a good way, this way you don't have to write your API manager totally from scratch. It also has some more benefits thats worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks!. How can I custom response data and manager it by Moya ?